# Proxy with mapped types

Tags: typescript, type-alias, mapped-types

I walk through [TS Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and I came to the mapped types. There is a code snippet to wrap object property into proxy.

```
type Proxy<T> = {
    get(): T;
    set(value: T): void;
}
type Proxify<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Proxy<T[P]>;
}
function proxify<T>(o: T): Proxify<T> {
   // ... wrap proxies ...
}
let proxyProps = proxify(props);
```

I'm trying to fill the gap in the *proxify* function with my implementation of it, and I get something like this:

```
function proxify<T>(t: T): Proxify<T> {
    let result = <Proxify<T>>{};
    for (const k in t) {
      result[k] = {    //(*) from that moment I lose strong typing  
        get: () => t[k],
        set: (value) => t[k] = value
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

I can't control types inside the loop and everything must by of *any* type there. How to cope with that, assuming that my implementation is correct at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation seems ok. While creating the object there is some safety lost but you don't loose it all. The amount of typing you still get might actually surprise you

```
function proxify<T>(t: T): Proxify<T> {
    let result = <Proxify<T>>{};
    for (const k in t) { // k is of type Extract<keyof T, string> so it must be a key of T
        // result[k] and t[k] both work because k is a key of both T and Proxify<T> but result['random'] would be invalid
        result[k] = { // get/set fields are checked, so _get would be an error
            // the return of get must be T[Extract<keyof T, string>] so ()=> 0 would be an error
            get: () => t[k],
            // value and t[k] must be T[Extract<keyof T, string>] so t[k] = '' would also be an error
            set: (value) => t[k] = value
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Titian. From time to time (my whole adventure with TS lasts somehow 2 week ;)) I have doubts about TS as a language and it's error messaging abstraction. I have got quite deep experience with C# and for me TS is quite natural, but I've got such experience. I don't think people with JS roots without experience with strong typing languages are able to understand the idea behind TS.

Answer (score 1):

My version of implementation is as below. I couldn't find a way to force type safety in get and set. It could be more elegant if there was some way to write properties like this get():PropType , set(value:PropType)

```
function proxify<T>(o: T): Proxify<T> {
        const proxifyObj: Proxify<T> = <Proxify<T>>{};
        Object.keys(o).map((key) => {
            proxifyObj[key] = {
                get() {
                    return o[key];
                },
                set(value) {
                    o[key] = value;
                }
            };

        });
        return proxifyObj;
    }
```